# IndexError: list index out of range - Opening file from cli - argv[1]

Tags: python, cron

With this method:

```
import croniter
import datetime
import re
import time
from sys import argv

now=datetime.datetime.now()

def main():
    filename=open(sys.argv[1])
    f1 = filename.readlines() 
    for x in f1:
        if not re.match('^[0-9*]', x):
            continue
        a = re.split(r'\s+', x)
        cron = croniter.croniter(' '.join(a[:5]), now)
        print("%s %s" % (cron.get_next(datetime.datetime), ' '.join(a[5:])))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm aiming to open a file (a crontab one, provided on stdin), but this line: `filename=open(sys.argv[1])` is throwing me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cron.py", line 25, in <module>
main()
File "cron.py", line 13, in main
filename=open(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm using this script like this: `python cron.py < /etc/crontab`

I double checked examples given about opening a file in this way, and it just seems to be fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: try `python cron.py /etc/crontab`

Comment: Yeah, just remove the `<` and it should work as expected

Comment: Can you confirm that `$ cat /etc/crontab` is non-empty?

Comment: LOL, haha, thanks, but, is there a way to specify it with the '<', or better not to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def main():
    filename=open(sys.argv[1])
```

that would work with `python cron.py /etc/crontab`.

But instead, you have no arguments, and feeding input using `stdin`

Change to:

```
filename = sys.stdin
```

(and don't close it)

Aside: `filename` is ill-chosen, since it's a file handle. That adds to the confusion between input stream and input file.

Comment: Thank You very much, yeah, gotta change 'filename', I'm gonna accept your answer in 10 minutes, SO doesn't let me to accept it before